# Brother QL500 fails to print after update to LTS 22.04

Tags: drivers, printing

My Brother QL 500 label printer has stopped working since an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 . the printer notification says the file has been printed but nothing is actually printed and the printer LED just flashes (the usual warning of some sort of error). Looking at the CUPS web interface the  "state" column says
`completed at Mon 06 Mar 2023 12:10:59 AEDT  "Use "pdftops-renderer" option (see cups-filters README file) to use Ghostscript or MuPDF for the PDF -> PostScript conversion.enter code here`

But I'm not sure if this is an error message or normal .

I have removed the printer the reinstalled it in "Settings" but it didn't change anything. Are there any other checks I can run to give some clues as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

OK I fixed the problem . In Settings/Printers/QL-500/settings/ in the drop down menu for Printing Options the upgrade process had set the "Paper Type" to "continuous roll"  I am using labels I changed the setting (back) to "Die-cut Labels" and everything works as it should.